# Method using StringBuffer for deleting dups

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I'm writing a method for deleting dups from a String using StringBuffer. The method is returning StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. How can I fix it ?

```
public static void removeDups( String myString ){

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( myString );
        int len =  myString.length(); 

        for ( int j = 0; j < len; j++ ){

            char c = sb.charAt(j);

            for ( int k = len - 1 ; k > j ; k-- ){

                if ( sb.charAt(k) == c ){

                    sb.deleteCharAt(k);
                    len--; 
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println("After deleting the dups : " + sb.toString() ); 
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Technically, it isn't returning `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` it is throwing it. For future references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int k = len - 1 ; k > j ; k++ )
```

If you're trying to iterate downwards, it needs to be `k--`, not `k++`.  Right now, the second iteration is going to have `k = len`, and that's out of bounds.  You're updating upwards infinitely instead of down to a bound.

You're also missing a bracket: it needs to be

```
 if ( sb.charAt(k) == c ) {
    sb.deleteCharAt(k);
    len--; 
 }
```

(While we're at it, there is essentially no reason ever to use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`, which provides ~the same API without synchronization overhead.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I changed it, but, still the method deletes one repetition. Say, when I put "njznj" it will print "njzj".

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the bracket. I also write some Python and thought it will cover two lines without the bracket. Now, the program is fine and thanks for your effort.

Comment: and "while we're at it", deleting characters (or short substrings) from StringBuilder repeatedly is almost always a lot slower than copying the parts that should remain, as delete will have to move all the text after the deletion point.